# MYSQL - IN BOOLEAN MODE Not working?

Tags: mysql

i have this query to get results from my database:

```
SELECT * FROM thomsenreuters.worldcheck WHERE MATCH (LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,ALIASES) AGAINST ('+ali +mohamed' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I works, but i got results which are useless...check this one:

LAST_NAME:
ABDELMOUMENE

FIRST_NAME:
Mohamed Larbi

ALIASES is empty.

so as you can see, the result is a little bit strange.
So what must i change that mysql is searching exact for the result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using MyISAM, correct?  And `ft_min_word_len` is 4, correct?

`ali` is too short, so it is silently ignored.

If you choose to change `ft_min_word_len`, remember to rebuild the FT index.

Did you know that InnoDB now supports `FULLTEXT`?  (But there are handful of differences.)

Comment: stop word list, that was my solution! Thank to @Rick James